# Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode when run query

Tags: python, unicode, encode, py2neo

I have a problem when i run a query with py2neo:

```
posts = graph.run(
            'MATCH (p:Post) WHERE p.post CONTAINS \'' + keyword + '\' '
            'AND p.timestamp>' + str(startDate) +
            ' AND p.timestamp<' + str(endDate) +
            ' return p').data()
print json.dumps(posts)
```

It works perfectly, but when the keyword is a word which contains a latin letter (like giovedì), I have this error 'Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode'. However, if I use another word which doesn't have any latin letter in the same p.Post, I don't get any error. Why ?

I have tried to use match.where() function to bypass this warning, but I don't understand how to use multiple clauses where:

```
list(match("Post").where(post__contains=keyword, timestamp__gt=startDate, timestamp__lt=endDate))
```

But it doesn't print anything

Comment: It means that two strings are encoded differently. Giving the full stack trace would allow a better analysis of the problem, but I'm guessing that decoding `keyword` would help. You need to find out what it is encoded with first, though (ie. UTF-8, CP-1252, Mac-Roman etc.).

Comment: how can I find the encoding of ```keyword```?

Comment: Well, where/how do you get `keyword`? Is it read from a file on disk, entered via command line, sent over HTTP? Different protocols have different ways of specifying text encoding. Unfortunately, there's also the situation that you have to guess.

Comment: @lenz I run the python script where I run ```graph.run(*)``` from a php script using the command ```shell_exec('python path/to/file $_POST['data'] 2>&1')```. Then, in python I, at first, use the split function on ```sys.argv[1]``` and then I use ```keyword = sys.argv[1].replace('_keyword_:', '')``` to obtain te var ```keyword```

Comment: In this case, you need to find out how PHP handles encoding here (in the `shell_exec` command). Maybe it doesn't and just passes on the bytes it got somewhere; in that case, you have to reach further back in the chain. Once you know the encoding, use it to decode `keyword`. Or just tryUTF-8, since Python will tell you if you guessed wrong with this one. That is: `keyword = keyword.decode('utf8')`.